# Alternative to iTunes for Podcasts

Tags: macos, itunes, podcasts

I listen to podcasts using iTunes (my only reason to use it), and I am growing to hate it. Can someone suggest an alternative that:

- Will not download the podcast unless I specifically do so.
- Will play a podcast to the end, and then stop.  What happens next is for me to decide, not the app (this is why I cannot stand iTunes anymore).
- Make it reasonably easy to find the podcasts I listen to and add them to a list.
- List all available episodes for a podcast, ideally with the summery if that is available.

BTW, I use my laptop to listen to podcasts.

Alternatively, if there is a way of stopping iTunes from autoplaying podcasts once one is finished, that would be an option too.

Answer (score 1):

[Downcast](http://www.downcastapp.com) is a 3rd party podcast player you should try out.

Downcast has native apps for macOS, iOS, watchOS and also include CarPlay support. It include support for host of features along with iCloud syncing across various platforms.

Comment: It looks promising -- is there a way of try before you buy?  it is cheap enough but still...

Comment: @user1256923 Purchase the app normally. You can always [request Apple for a refund](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204084#problem) (That's what I do :)).